# SQL Ordering Data from row "n+1" to "n-1"

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a simple question. In MySQL, consider a row "n", how can we order rows by id (for example), but start from the row "n+1" and end to the row "n-1" ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :** I ommit to precise that I seek the query in MySQL.

From an answer below, here an example :

```
ID
---
1
2
3
4   <--N
5
6
```

I want Desired Results ordered as follows

```
5   <--N + 1
6
1
2
3   <--N - 1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results?  Also, which RDBMS as there may be quicker solutions that are vendor specific.

Comment: You mean you only need 3 rows in the result (n + 1, n, n - 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mean. For a table

```
ID
---
1
2
3
4   <--N
5
6
```

You want Desired Results ordered as follows?

```
5   <--N + 1
6
1
2
3   <--N - 1
```

If so

```
SELECT ID
FROM T
WHERE ID <> 4
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID > 4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You understood as well my requirement. But I ommit to say that I seek the query for MySQL. I'm editing my question.

Comment: @MehdiChamouma -  This answer is standard SQL and works in MySQL. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d9bc/1)

Comment: My mistake. I need this for Doctrine2 (in DQL) and Case statement is not availaible. So I'll repost for a more specific request. Thank a lot !

Comment: @MehdiChamouma - Ah I've never used DQL so I have no idea if there is any simple equivalent to `CASE` there.

Comment: wouldn't using the `if` statement be easier since it's only 1 case ? `ORDER BY if(ID > 4,0,1)`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes. That is not standard SQL though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table `MyTable` with integer column `N`:

```
SELECT *
 from MyTable
 where Id between N-1 and N+1
 order by N desc
```

Answer (score -1):

You're asking how to sort by descending ?

Just stick

```
ORDER BY col a , col b DESC;
```

at the end

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP question.